# jekyll & markdown, how to force new section style

Tags: css, formatting, markdown

In the following markdown code example how can you avoid to have the new section title wrap on the left of the image if the text on its left is not long enough to reach its bottom.

```
![placeholder](/path/image.png){::class="img-left-150"}
text and a [link](mylink).
# new section
new text
```

with in the css file

```
.img-left-150 {
               display: block;
               max-width: 150px;
               float: left;
               margin-right: 1rem;
               }
```

Comment: writing inline style attributes is usually bad practice... I'd go with a dedicated CSS style sheet..

Comment: I edited my question, and add a css style sheet. but unless i am missing something the problem remains